# moving a selected number of images in folder to another folder

Tags: python

i have 1200 images in source_folder, i want to copy only 500 images randomly and put them in the destination folder.
all the images names are in the list:
`List = ['1.jpg, '2.jpg', '3.jpg', ...., '1200.jpg']`

```py
import glob, random
file_path_type = ["./source_folder/*.jpg"]
images = glob.glob(random.choice(file_path_type))
random_image = random.choice(images)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "glob" to get the whole list.  Shuffle that list, and pick off the first 500.  Note that `random.shuffle` shuffles in place.

```
import os, glob, random
files = glob.glob("./source_folder/*.jpg")
random.shuffle(files)
for name in files[:500]:
    os.rename( name, "destination_folder")
```

Comment: i had an error in the last line of code, NotADirectory

Comment: Did you create the destination folder first?

Comment: Yes I did, I have created a folder before running the code

Comment: Well, if the "current directory" contains the destination folder, then that code must work.  Perhaps you're not in the directory you think you are.